# PHP Cookie works unless set as variable

Tags: php, cookies

This is specific to the server I am on but I cannot figure out what is going on.

```
$ref = $_COOKIE['ref'];

echo $_COOKIE['ref']; // returns perfectly
echo $ref; // returns nothing.
```

I am simply confused, never seen a problem like this before.

```
var_dump($_COOKIE, $ref);
```

returns:

```
["_ga"]=&gt;
string(26) "GA1.2.788346574.1519086454"
["_gid"]=&gt;
string(26) "GA1.2.119524094.1519086454"
["NEWSESSID"]=&gt;
string(26) "***********************"
["ref"]=&gt;
string(4) "8696"
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of `var_dump($_COOKIE, $ref);`? FYI, `var_dump()` shows **types** and values

Comment: You are absolutely sure there is nothing in between that could overwrite `$ref`?

Comment: I updated with the vardump, I am 100% sure nothing is in between. I can directly set the cookie, the variable, then the echos, only the echo cookie is returned.

Comment: hangon: when and how do you set the cookie? (if you do a setcookie, then $_COOKIE won't be available in the next line)

Comment: What I mean is, I can set the cookie, refresh the page, and only the echo of $_COOKIE['ref']; is returned, not the echo of $ref; 

As stated this is a server specific issue. I have tested this on a different server and the same code works perfectly returning both echo's, which is why I am so baffled.

Comment: That output doesn't look right. I would expect the first line for `var_dump($_COOKIE)` to be `array(4) {`. And where is the output for `$ref`? I don't think you're showing us everything. `var_dump()` shouldn't be encoding HTML entities either.

Comment: I actually was showing everything, however I sorted the issue, it seemed to be related to mod_security. When I disabled it, all things seem to return normally.